# Where should I implement forgot password feature in a microservice app?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, yaml, microservices

I have this rabbitmq service and deplyment in a kubernetes cluster and i tested this in my browser and I have acccess to it.

However I am unable to achieve a connection to it using node .js

The error i get is

```
[auth] OperationalError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
[auth]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1137:16) {
[auth]   cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
[auth]       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1137:16) {
[auth]     errno: -111,
[auth]     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[auth]     syscall: 'connect',
[auth]     address: '127.0.0.1',
[auth]     port: 8080
[auth]   },
[auth]   isOperational: true,
[auth]   errno: -111,
[auth]   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[auth]   syscall: 'connect',
[auth]   address: '127.0.0.1',
[auth]   p
```

which basically means it refusing to connect.

I have tried `kubectl port-forward rabbitmq-depl-64f964cbbb-tnwbj  8080:15672` to expose that pod to the outside world and connect to it via connect('"amqp://127.0.0.1:8080") but its not working

I also tried to map that service in my node.js server yaml file such as

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: verification-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: verification
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: verification
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: verification
          image: sn/verification
          env:
            - name: NATS_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name # pod name as env for clinet id
            - name: NATS_URL
              value: 'http://nats-srv:4222'
            - name: RABITMQ_URL
              value: 'rabbitmq:15672'
            - name: NATS_CLUSTER_ID
              value: snsocial
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: sn-jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: verification-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: verification
  ports:
    - name: verification
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

but no luck. the localhost works fine on the browser however its not working in my service. i trie to play with to use
const rbmqConnection = await amqp.connect(`amqp://${SERVICE_URL}`)

**but no luck.**
rabbitmq-depl.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-depl
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rabbitmq
          image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 15672
            - containerPort: 5672
          env:
            - name: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
              value: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
              value: "guest"
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
              value: "guest"
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST
              value: "/"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15672
    - name: amqp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
```

what am I doing wrong here.

you can see my nats server working fine and I am able to connect to it with no issue but I need to try rabbitmq in a cluster because it provides message storage unlike nats streaming.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get over it.

*rabbitmq-depl.yaml*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-depl
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rabbitmq
          image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 15672
            - containerPort: 5672
          env:
            - name: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
              value: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
              value: "guest"
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
              value: "guest"
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST
              value: "/"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15672
    - name: amqp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
  selector:
    app: rabbitm
```

**auth-depl.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: sn/auth
          env:
            - name: NATS_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name # pod name as env for clinet id
            - name: NATS_URL
              value: 'http://nats-srv:4222'
            - name: CONNECTION_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name # pod name as env for clinet id
            - name : RABBITMQ_ULR 
              value : amqp://rabbitmq

            - name: NATS_CLUSTER_ID
              value: snsocial
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: sn-jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

Basically I had almost everything right but in the auth service, i had the wrong env values, the connection name should have been ampq://(name of service) and then in node.js code, all I had to do is to say, `process.env.RABBITMQ_URL`